# Python unittest returns "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s" and I have no idea why

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm stuck with this problem and I have no idea why this test doesn't work. Please anyone help me.

Code below is in the cityname.py file

```
def get_name(city, country):
    return (city.title() + ", " + country.title())
```

Code below is in the test_cities.py file

```
import unittest

from cityname import get_name

class CitiesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_city_country(self):
        santiago_chile = get_name('santiago', 'chile')
        self.assertEqual(santiago_chile, 'Santiago, Chile')

unittest.main()
```

Here is the output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: If the indentation in the code you posted matches what's in your file, then it's because the `test_city_country` function doesn't belong to `CitiesTestCase` due to not being indented

Comment: Works for me. How do you run it?

Comment: I know it should work but it doesn't I guess there may be some sort of problem in importing my files(?) and I have no idea what to do with it. I'm running it in normally in pycharm there's no way I'm running it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either remove `unittest.main()`
2. Or pass the argument `exit=False`, `unittest.main(exit=False)`
3. Or surround `unittest.main(`) with this `if` statment

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':

       unittest.main()
   ```

Your can read more about how this works in the Python docs...
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.main

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's that I have both python2 and python3 installed, and "python" refers to py2. "python -m unittest -v" always return "Ran 0 test" which is fixed by "python3 -m unittest -v"